# Saving object to be accessible anywhere

Tags: ios, swift

I have a condition hereby let's say a user has logged in by calling an API. And the response contain's user's details. Is there anyway we can save the details of the user as an object and be accessible globally? Below is how I used ObjectMapper to call the api
For the model class:

```
import ObjectMapper

class User: Mappable {

var id: Int?
var userId: Int?
var orgId: Int?
var type: Int?
var email: String?
var lang: String?
var nickname: String?
var status: Int?
var token: String?

required init(map: Map) {
    mapping(map: map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    userId <- map["userId"]
    orgId <- map["orgId"]
    type <- map["type"]
    failedAttempt <- map["failedAttempt"]
    email <- map["email"]
    lang <- map["lang"]
    nickname <- map["nickname"]
    status <- map["status"]
    token <- map["token"]
}
```

}

And from my Networking file,

```
    func postLogin(params: [String: Any], controller: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {
    alamofire("/login", method: .post, token: false, params: params, controller: controller) { result in
        if let userDetails = Mapper<User>().map(JSON: result as! [String: Any]) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(userDetails)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some solutions may be using UserDefaults but it's just not practical to be using 9 UserDefaults to save the 9 keys that we got from this response. What are the suggested ways of approach we can go about this where user logged in, we save these details as an object globally and even when after closing the app, the details are not reseted? Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that saving 9 individual keys in `UserDefaults` is not practical.  But why not encode the whole thing as JSON and save the resulting `Data`?

```swift
extension User: Codable { }

// Assuming user is an instance of User
guard let userJSON = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) else {
    // handle encoding failure
}

let userDefaultsKeyForUser = "com.yourdomain.snazzyapp.userInfo"

UserDefaults.standard.set(userJSON, forKey: userDefaultsKeyForUser)
```

I think Swift will automatically synthesize `Codable` conformance for your `User` class, but you might need to make it `final`.  Or implement `Codable` explicitly.

To retrieve it

```swift
guard let userJSON = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: userDefaultsKeyForUser) else {
    // Handle missing data (first run maybe?)
}

guard let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: userJSON) else {
   // Handle decoding failure
}
```

#### Alternative encoding/decoding methods

Although conforming to `Codable` would be the preferred way to do this, that can sometimes be a problem for classes, particularly when inheritance is involved.  In particular `Codable` is a combination of `Encodable` and `Decodable`.  `Decodable` is the one that is sometimes a problem for classes.  The issue has to do with the `required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` having to be declared directly in the class, not in an extension, and then you might have trouble with encoding the `super`.   If your class is the base `class` that shouldn't be a problem.  This is mainly a problem when you inherit from AppKit/UIKit classes.

If for some reason `User` can't conform to `Codable`, you can use `NSCoding` instead.  It works a little differently.

In the worst case you could implement methods where you manually encode/decode each property explicitly to data.  You could even store them as binary, but you'll probably need to do something like store byte counts for the strings so you know where each one starts and ends, and you'll need to come up with a scheme to indicate when they are `nil` in the encoding.  It's not as flexible as JSON, which is why it's a last resort... although I will note that it is much faster.  That wouldn't matter much for your `User` class, but I wrote a neural network library where I wanted to save the model at checkpoints during training, which meant encoding many layers of very large matrices.  Millions of parameters. Reading and writing the model was about 20x faster with my own binary encoding than letting `Codable` handle it, even when I had `Codable` saving it as a binary plist.

A third option would be to re-work your `User` class.  Either make it a `struct`, or use a `struct` internally to store its properties and use computed properties to get and set them in your `class`.  All of your class's properties already conform to `Codable`, so Swift can definitely synthesize `Codable` conformance for a `struct` with those properties.   If you still wrap the `struct` inside of a `class`, then you just have an initializer that takes a `Data`, and do the same decoding I showed above, to set the wrapped `struct`, and an `encode` method (or even a computed `var`) that encodes the `struct` as above and returns the `Data`.

I don't think you'll need these alternate solutions, but I mention them just in case I'm wrong, and because they're useful to know about for future situations.

Comment: Hmm... and how would u retrieve it? As normally how we retrieve from userdefaults, only addition is to to cast it back to User once retrieved?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `UserDefaults` you could just read/write `userJSON` from/to a file in a known location in your app's sandbox.

Comment: If you do use `UserDefaults.standard`, you might want to prepend the the key with the same bundle identifier you use for your app... maybe something like "com.yourdomain.snazzyapp.userInfo"

Comment: Updated again to reflect my suggestion about `UserDefaults` key naming, but also my initial call to `JSONEncoder().encode()` was encoding `userJSON`, when it should have been encoding `user`, so I corrected that too.

Comment: Sorry for the many edits of my answer.  I'm convinced that the most effective proof reading tool in the world is a "Post" button, and I when I'm editing README files in repos, I think `git commit` should be renamed to `git reveal-grammar-errors`, because that seems to be the effect on me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself how you would like to access this object with compilator autocompletion from different places in your app. Secondly, what is the life span of the object? The object should be accessible during login / logout, app session or app life time?

**Let's start with the object life span.**

- login / logout, the object can be stored in memory
- app session, the object can be stored in memory
- app install / delete, the object should be stored in UserDefaults, Database or a file.

---

**Autocompletion Driven Development aka ADD**:

*Deciding where to store userDetails object and how to access it*

Let's say that you have a logic in a view controller which hide or unhide a view in a initial configuration defined in viewDidLoad. Write some prototype code to decide how you would like to access the 'userDetails' object from different places of the app.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if userDetails.status {
     //userDetails is a global instance of a user object
   }

   if session.userDetails.status {
     //session is a global instance of a Session object which has a property which stores a User instance in userDetails
   }

   if Session.current.userDetails.status {
     // Session is a type and 'current' is a singleton of that type which has a userDetails property which stores an instance of User type
   }

   if User.userDetails.status {
     // User is your type which can have a static property 'userDetails' which stores a User instance
   }

}
```